# Allure Title annotation

Tags: testng, title, allure

Does [Allure Report](https://allurereport.org/) able to show test name without changes by default?

**Current behaviour:** It separates test name by words and set up capital case for each word in test name.

I'm using `TestNG` testing framework.

**Example:**

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public void testExample() {
  //do smth
}
```

Will show me 'Test Example' under frontend.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.annotations.Title;

@Title('testExample')
@Test
public void testExample() {
  //do smth
}
```

Will show me 'testExample' under frontend.

I don't want to duplicate test name in @Title annotation every test.
How can avoid to write @Title annotation above each test?

Answer (score 2):

You can see a method name at the top of the test case page:

[image: The top of the test case page]

For now there is no way to change this behavior - but we are going to remove title generation feature. See related Github issue - https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues/408.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will wait removing of this weird behaviour. As workaround i applied Title annotation with test name for all existing tests using regexp.